# Print screen in Windows XP

Tags: windows, adobe-reader

When using Windows XP SP3, when I want to print the screen I use a program called Printkey2000. When Printkey2000 executes, I click on the "print" button, but instead of sending it to my printer for a hard copy I want to save it as a .pdf file. I accomplish this using another program called doPDF v5. After saving it successfully to the location of my choice, Adobe Acrobat finds it necessary to bring up a page to show me what I just saved. How do I turn off Acrobat from doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not Acrobat - it's actually doPDF v5 activating that printed document. Does doPDF v5 have any configurable options you can get at?

You might want to look into using [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/) or [PDFCreator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/) instead, as it has the option to not show the PDF document after printing.

Comment: +1 (see my comment to surfmadpig's response :)

Comment: You get the check mark Caliban. PDF Creator did the trick. I saw the option to turn off printing the saved file with default viewer. Can't tell you how long this has been annoying me, since I do a lot of print screens.

Comment: Glad it helped you :). Sometimes life's biggest annoyances comes from the smallest things. Well, looks like you got rid of one today! Have a great weekend.

Answer (score 0):

I also use doPDF and haven't found an option to turn this behavior off. I guess there is none.

But if what annoys you is the fact that adobe reader pops up, and assuming that it takes a while to start for you too (as is the case for almost everyone), I'd suggest switching .pdf viewers to PDFx-change (http://www.docu-track.com/). I know this doesn't answer your question, but it can help you get over the adobe annoyances.

Comment: yep, this annoyed the heck out of me, so i went back to trusty old CutePDF. (and i do use pdf-xchange) i'm well able myself to open a newly saved PDF if i feel so inclined. :)